# How to shorten my jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code.
https://jsfiddle.net/f6m6k0w8/

Is there a better way to shorten the code below without changing the HTML structure?

```
$(element).parent().prev().children('select[name="custom_type"]').val()
```

Comment: Pardon me for my wrong answer. Somehow here `parents()` in `$.each`  is always clinging on to first `select` tag. Don't know why. Feeling bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$(element).closest('.grid_wrap').find('[name="custom_type"]').val()
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/f6m6k0w8/1/)**

<kbd>**[.closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)**</kbd> finds closest element mentioned by traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree. So basically find its `closest` base parent and then use find to get `element`

Answer (score 2):

If you not only want short code, but also *optimized* code.

As you're looping using `each()`, you can use the index to get the corresponding element value. Using this you can avoid some function calls like `parent()`, `closest()` inside loop to get the element value.

```
$('select[name="custom_type"]').eq(index).val(),
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/f6m6k0w8/3/)

Also, check the optimized code.

```js
$('input[type=button]').click(function() {
  var attribute = [];

  // Cache the elements
  var $customValues = $('select[name="custom_type"]');

  $('input[name="custom_value"]').each(function(index, element) {
    var row = {
      type: $customValues.eq(index).val(), // Get value of corresponding element from cache
      value: element.value
    };
    attribute.push(row);
  });
  $('.result').html(JSON.stringify(attribute));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>row 1</p>
<div class="grid_wrap">
  <div class="grid_row">
    <select name="custom_type">
      <option value="A">type A</option>
      <option value="B">type B</option>
      <option value="C">type C</option>
      <option value="D" selected="selected">type D</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="grid_row">
    <input type="text" name="custom_value" value="Derrick Rose" />
  </div>
</div>
<p>row 2</p>
<div class="grid_wrap">
  <div class="grid_row">
    <select name="custom_type">
      <option value="A">type A</option>
      <option value="B">type B</option>
      <option value="C" selected="selected">type C</option>
      <option value="D">type D</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="grid_row">
    <input type="text" name="custom_value" value="Camelo Anthony" />
  </div>
</div>
<p>row 3</p>
<div class="grid_wrap">
  <div class="grid_row">
    <select name="custom_type">
      <option value="A">type A</option>
      <option value="B" selected="selected">type B</option>
      <option value="C">type C</option>
      <option value="D">type D</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="grid_row">
    <input type="text" name="custom_value" value="Brandon Roy" />
  </div>
</div>
<p>
  <input type="button" value="show console" />
</p>
<div class="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest) and [.map()](https://api.jquery.com/map) clean up some of the code

```js
$(function() {
  $('input[type=button]').click(function() {
    var attribute = $('input[name="custom_value"]').map(function(index, element) {
      var row = {
        type: $(element).closest('.grid_wrap').find('select[name="custom_type"]').val(),
        value: element.value
      };
      return row;
    }).get();
    $('.result').html(JSON.stringify(attribute));
    console.log(attribute);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>row 1</p>
<div class="grid_wrap">
  <div class="grid_row">
    <select name="custom_type">
      <option value="A">type A</option>
      <option value="B">type B</option>
      <option value="C">type C</option>
      <option value="D" selected="selected">type D</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="grid_row">
    <input type="text" name="custom_value" value="Derrick Rose" />
  </div>
</div>
<p>row 2</p>
<div class="grid_wrap">
  <div class="grid_row">
    <select name="custom_type">
      <option value="A">type A</option>
      <option value="B">type B</option>
      <option value="C" selected="selected">type C</option>
      <option value="D">type D</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="grid_row">
    <input type="text" name="custom_value" value="Camelo Anthony" />
  </div>
</div>
<p>row 3</p>
<div class="grid_wrap">
  <div class="grid_row">
    <select name="custom_type">
      <option value="A">type A</option>
      <option value="B" selected="selected">type B</option>
      <option value="C">type C</option>
      <option value="D">type D</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="grid_row">
    <input type="text" name="custom_value" value="Brandon Roy" />
  </div>
</div>
<p>
  <input type="button" value="show console" />
</p>
<div class="result"></div>
```